# How to execute a shell script as a result of an aws auto-scale event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

## Background

I got the following setup with AWS code deploy:
[image]

Currently we have our EC2 application servers connected to an auto-scaling group, but there is a missing step: once a new server is fired up, we don't automatically deploy the latest code on it from our git repo

## Question

I was going over [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html#lifecycle-hooks-overview) tutorial: 
Basically i want to run a bunch of commands as soon as an instance is launched but before it's hooked up to the load balancer.

The above tutorial describes things in general, but I couldn't answer the following questions:

1. Where do I save the script on the ec2 instance?
2. How is that script executed once the instance is scaled in but before its connected to the load balancer?

Comment: I believe you can git pull the code by writing a script of any kind, python, bash etc.. in the user data section. Your keyword is userdata aws ec2 instances

Comment: can you maybe use codedeploy for this purpose, because this service is designed for exactly that purpose. On your git repo you make a hook for deploying a new version to codedeploy and once a new instance is spinned up & codedeploy deployed during the init script it will look for the latest version of the deployment. As a plus, you can also upgrade/rollback your app with it. I have seen it running in a reasonably large installation for many apps.

Comment: you can go the path mentioned by @petrch

Comment: code deploy can be linked directly to ASG and scripts may be part of the deployment, so after you uploaded the image I can understand the problem less than before.

Comment: i updated my question, we *already* use code deploy, but code deploy is triggered manually (in our case we connected to a bitbucket pipeline that is triggered by pushing to a git branch).. what I'm asking for is different, I want the action of pulling from a git repo to happen in response to an auto-scale hook

Comment: @petrch how to link code deploy to ASG? do you have a tutorial/reference?

Comment: I'm looking at this now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html

Comment: @abbood the link is correct. When you create Deployment group in CodeDeploy you can select autoscaling group. That way you apply the deployment to all instances including the future ones in the ASG.

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to life cycle hook, the life cycle is useful when you want to perform an action in different stats like stop, start and terminate but you just to pull the latest code and some other commands.

To answer your Question I will suggest below approach, as there are many many more approaches for the same task.

1. You do not need to save the script or command, place them on s3 or you can run commands just put them in the `user data` in your launch configuration. You can run them as bash script or you can pull your scripts from aws s3.

[image]

This can be the simplest example to handle pull code case. So this will run whenever a new instance launch in this auto-scaling group.
Another example can be to run a complex script, place them on s3 and pull them during scaling up.

[image]

I assume you already set permission for s3 and bitbucket. You can run any complex during this time.

2. The second steps are a bit tricky, you can use a different approach, the instance will never receive traffic until its healthy so start your application once your code updated and all the required scripts done execution than at the end you can run your application.

Another approach can be

**a):Health Check Grace Period**

> Frequently, an Auto Scaling instance that has just come into service
>   needs to **warm up** before it can pass the health check. Amazon EC2
>   Auto Scaling waits until the health check grace period ends before
>   checking the health status of the instance.

**b)Custom Health Checks**

> If you have your own health check system, you can send the instance's
>   health information directly from your system to Amazon EC2 Auto
>   Scaling.
>
> Use the following set-instance-health command to set the health state
>   of the specified instance to Unhealthy.

```
aws autoscaling set-instance-health --instance-id i-123abc45d --health-status healthy
```

You can get instance-id using curl call, the script that we place in the userdata.

**If you have custom health checks, you can send the information from your health checks to Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling so that Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can use this information. For example, if you determine that an instance is not functioning as expected, you can set the health status of the instance to Unhealthy. The next time that Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling performs a health check on the instance, it will determine that the instance is unhealthy and then launch a replacement instance.**

**c)Instance Warmup**

> With step scaling policies, you can specify the number of seconds that
>   it takes for a newly launched instance to warm up. Until its specified
>   warm-up time has expired, an instance is not counted toward the
>   aggregated metrics of the Auto Scaling group. While scaling out, AWS
>   also does not consider instances that are warming up as part of the
>   current capacity of the group. Therefore, multiple alarm breaches that
>   fall in the range of the same step adjustment result in a single
>   scaling activity. This ensures that we don't add more instances than
>   you need.

Again, the second step is not that big deal, you can control the flow using your script and start the application at the end so then it will mark healthy,

You can also try [as-enter-exit-standby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-enter-exit-standby.html) but I think custom health checks for warm up can do this job.

Comment: It appears you changed the set-instance-health invocation line here from "unhealthy" to "healthy".  Does using set-instance-health to report a node as healthy really work as a delay-until-warmup scheme?  The autoscale group will see it as healthy when the health check returns and warmup time expires (whether your warmup has completed or no).  Will `set-instance-health --health-status healthy` short circuit the warmup time?

I would think enter/exit-standby would be the right answer here.